# Create folder with mkdir with loop in Bash

Tags: bash, mkdir

I want to create folders in bash but taking the months as reference in loop, the month in curse and the future months, i have already this code that generate the first folder.

```
echo "probando desde vim" 
echo "vim" 
if [ -d "$HOME/Desktop/$(date +%b)" ] 
  then 
  echo "Si Existe" 
else 
  mkdir $HOME/Desktop/$(date +%b) 
  echo "La carpeta fue creada" 
fi 
!/bin/bash HOME_DIRS="$HOME/Desktop/" DATE_DIR=$(date +%B) for FOLDER in $HOME/desktop/; do mkdir -p "${FOLDER}/${DATE_DIR}" done
```

Comment: You should be able to edit your answer.  Be sure to indent the code 4 spaces so that it displays properly.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey I have edited it for him. Seems a first timer...

Comment: @iamauser, You're a good man sir!